# Is there any sort of correlation between melting point and the degrees of freedom for the molecules of a substance?

Tags: phase, melting-point, free-energy

Suppose I had a solid whose molecules did not have rotational freedom. But if I were able to make it so that the molecules had rotational freedom ceteris paribus, is there a way to tell how the melting point would change compared to the original solid. Here I assume that the molecules have rotational freedom in the liquid phase always.

Comment: It should increase as for entropy of the melting should diminish. Assuming nothing else change in the forces leading to the solid, which seems magic.